# Halaster's Light Step against Blindsight, Blindsense and Tremorsense

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells, stealth

Looking at Halaster's Light Step (City of Splendors: Waterdeep, p. 154) I was wondering: Would this spell, combined with some form of invisibility, effectively make Blindsight, Blindsense and Tremorsense useless? As well as making Darkstalker somewhat redundant for casters? Or is there something im missing?

Comment: It might be useful to (1) identify the source of the spell (some spells have been published multiple times, with differences) and (2) cite the relevant part of the spell which motivates the question. The version I found (*City of Splendors: Waterdeep*, p. 154) would probably negate TremorSense, but have no effect on BlindSight/BlindSense.

Comment: Edited for clarity. And yes that is precisely the one I'm talking about

Comment: I removed the copy-pasted block of non-OGL, copyrighted text. (If someone doesn't have access to the book, they shouldn't be answering questions about it anyway.) If you want to quote the specific sentences that make you wonder about this question, for clarity purposes, that's okay though.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, for our purpose, *Halaster's Light Step* is just like *Fly* with +10 *Circumstance* bonus to *Move Silently*.

---

The effect on special senses is easily deduced:

- The *Move Silently* bonus is useless, special senses use *Spot* vs *Hide*.
- **Tremorsense** (regular creature): foiled, as the subject is flying.
- **Tremorsense** (*Aquatic* creature): foiled if the subject is flying, not foiled if the subject is immersed.
- **Blindsight**, **Blindsense**: not foiled, bats use echo-location for example and locate flying mosquitoes without issue.

Adding *Invisibility* is useless against special senses, as they do not rely on sight to start with.

So, against *Tremorsense*, it gives the character a mechanical benefit: by avoiding contact with the ground/liquid, the character does not provoke vibrations which can be picked up.

---

The comparison to *Darkstalker* is rather meaningless as well. *Darkstalker* let you apply your *Hide* and *Move Silently* even against creatures whose special senses would normally bypass them; since *Halaster's Light Step* does not grant such benefits, it's really orthogonal.

Note that a character with the *Darkstalker* and under the effect of *Halaster's Light Step* could appreciate the +10 *Circumstance* bonus to *Move Silently*.

---

This does not make the spell useless, however. An invisible caster with +10 *Circumstance* bonus to *Move Silently* will be incredibly annoying to locate for the mundane goons; but even without being invisible, simply being able to  levitate out of range and not spring up any pressure-based trap is already a great utility. And not falling, of course.

At higher levels, of course, expect pervasive use of *Detect Magic*/*See Invisibility*/*True Seeing* which make magical invisibility much less effective (not even mentioning *Mindsight* or *Lifesense*...) and expect enemies with either flight abilities or ranged attack abilities. Then again, it's only a 2nd level spell.

Comment: What do you mean by saying "special senses use Spot vs Hide"? There are many and usualy Hide is nonfunctional vs them.

Comment: @annoyingimp: poorly phrased, I guess. I wanted to emphasize that the bonus to Move Silently was useless against the special senses cited: even with the DarkStalker feat, it would be a Spot vs Hide check.

Comment: If you pump your MS higher than Hide, you may gain benefits vs certain hypotetical enemies (who has high Spot but low Listen). Just a rare corner case, I guess. But I asked because I didn't get it it was about DarkStalker in the first place, and it was a reason why I asked. Thanks for clarification.